# Can I ignore warnings from scipy if using bounds with a minimizer in scipy (Python) that does not need bounds?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I run a set of minimizer methods from scipy.optimize.
I input bounds to the call of one particular method (Nelder-Mead) and scipy warns me:

```
RuntimeWarning: Method Nelder-Mead cannot handle constraints nor bounds.
```

The warning is clear: I shouldn't input bounds, but I actually input bounds for other reasons (to generalize my code and ignore special cases).

**Question**
Can I ignore this warning from scipy and still trust that Nelder-Mead is being used just as if I had not input any bounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

since 2021, Nelder-Mead can also handles bounds. If you upgrade Scipy to >1.7.1 it will not any longer ignore bounds, however you will also no longer get the warning.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**
I looked at the source code and found that indeed the warning can be ignored because calling with method "Nelder-Mead" just gets redirected to the call:

```
return _minimize_neldermead(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)
```

where clearly no bounds are present, so it should be fine.