# Limitation on parameters while minimizing the function

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I need to minimize the function depending on the angles of phi and teta. Using two loops, I create lists with sets of angles that are fed into the input before minimizing.

```
for i in range(1, 36):
    fi.append(10*i*math.pi/180)
for j in range(1, 36):
    theta.append(10*j*math.pi/180)

def f(params):
    phi, teta = params
    count = 0.
    for u in range(len(X)):
        count += ((R0[u] - X[u]*math.sin(teta)*math.cos(phi) - Y[u]*math.sin(teta)*math.sin(phi) - Z[u]*math.cos(teta))/(len(X) + 2))**2
    return count


for q in range(len(fi)):
    for w in range(len(theta)):
       p = []
       p = [fi[q], theta[w]]
       p = optimize.fmin(f, p, maxiter=SIMPLEX_CALCU_LIMIT, maxfun=(5*SIMPLEX_CALCU_LIMIT), xtol=SIMPLEX_SIZE_LIMIT, ftol=SIMPLEX_SIZE_LIMIT, full_output=True, disp=False)
```

But I need to introduce a restriction on the theta angle, which is obtained as a result of minimization. It should be in the range from 0 to pi. How to do it?

Maybe we need to add something to the expression string to minimize the function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If theta needs to be between 0 and pi, then why are you creating theta between 0 and 2pi?

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.optimize.minimize` has a `bounds` argument that allows you to set any restrictions to your input in a form of a list of (min, max) pairs. In your case that would be `bounds = [(None, None), (0, math.pi)]` for `phi` and `theta`, respectively.

`scipy.optimize.minimize` with the "Nelder-Mead" method should be equivalent to `scipy.optimize.fmin` above, so you can do something like:

```
p = scipy.optimize.minimize(f, p, method='Nelder-Mead', options=dict(maxiter=SIMPLEX_CALCU_LIMIT, maxfun=(5*SIMPLEX_CALCU_LIMIT), xtol=SIMPLEX_SIZE_LIMIT, ftol=SIMPLEX_SIZE_LIMIT, full_output=True, disp=False), bounds=[(None, None), (0, math.pi)])
```

For more details have a look at the signature of `minimize` - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: final_simplex: (array([[7.46226796, 8.16367798],
       [7.46226796, 8.16367798],
       [7.46226796, 8.16367798]]), array([800.1184879, 800.1184879, 800.1184879]))
           fun: 800.118487897113
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 170
           nit: 89
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([7.46226796, 8.16367798])

Comment: Are you sure that it is right?

Comment: Could you provide the inputs that give this result, so I can recreate it? Including any constant parameters (such as `SIMPLEX_CALCU_LIMIT`).

Comment: x = [127.45, -145.65, -272.17, 575.86, 197.5, -501.14, -508.54, 0, 0, 236.7, -342.53, -516.57, -50.92, 89.49]
y = [21.95, -33.72, -528.25, -282.23, 578.27, 279.06, 77.86, 0, 0, -979.55, 162.73, 80.12, 91.66, -158.43]
z = [28.5, -22.5, -99.6, -44.5, 26.5, -26.4, -24.6, 0, 0, -226.3, 6.4, -4.6, 26.6, -43.4]

SIMPLEX_SIZE_LIMIT = 1.e-8
SIMPLEX_CALCU_LIMIT = 1000
fi = []
theta = []
for i in range(1, 36):
    fi.append(10*i*math.pi/180)
for j in range(1, 9):
    theta.append(10*j*math.pi/180)

tim = [15083.5, 15304.5, 15531.0, 15752.0]
S = [1, 0, 12, 8]

Comment: X = []
Y = []
Z = []
T = []
R0 = []
residuals = []
val = []


for j in range(len(S)-1):
    X.append(x[S[j + 1]] - x[S[0]])
    Y.append(y[S[j + 1]] - y[S[0]])
    Z.append(z[S[j + 1]] - z[S[0]])
    T.append(tim[j + 1] - tim[0])
    R0.append(T[j] * 0.3)


def f(params):
    phi, teta = params
    count = 0.
    for u in range(len(X)):
        count += ((R0[u] - X[u]*math.sin(teta)*math.cos(phi) - Y[u]*math.sin(teta)*math.sin(phi) - Z[u]*math.cos(teta))/(len(X) + 2))**2
    return count

Comment: for q in range(len(fi)):
    for w in range(len(theta)):
        p = []
        p = [fi[q], theta[w]]
        p = optimize.minimize(f, p, method='Nelder-Mead', options=dict(maxiter=SIMPLEX_CALCU_LIMIT, maxfun=(5*SIMPLEX_CALCU_LIMIT), xtol=SIMPLEX_SIZE_LIMIT, ftol=SIMPLEX_SIZE_LIMIT, full_output=True, disp=False), bounds=[(0, 2*math.pi), (0, 0.5*math.pi)])
        print(p)

Comment: And also we have warning: Method Nelder-Mead cannot handle constraints nor bounds.

Comment: What is your `scipy` version? You might need to upgrade it in order to handle constraints/bounds - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68745449/16173463).

This is what I get (version `1.8.1` and `1.10.1`):

final_simplex: (array([[6.28318531, 0.38450034],
       [6.28318531, 0.38450033],
       [6.28318531, 0.38450033]]), array([1017.14220827, 1017.14220827, 1017.14220827]))
           fun: 1017.1422082749216
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 112
           nit: 61
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([6.28318531, 0.38450034])

Comment: Now i have version 1.11.4. It didn't help. There is OptimizeWarning: Unknown solver options: full_output, maxfun.

Comment: Both `fmin` and `minimize` with `method='Nelder-Mead'` call [`_minimize_neldermead`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py#L780), which has changed signature in `1.11.4`. Have a look at the docs and replace `full_option` and `maxfun` with `return_all` and `maxfev`, respectively.

I also ran the script with scipy version `1.11.4` and I get angles within the specified bounds, so it seems correct. Are there any other issues you encounter?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: As far as I understand, the fact is that you have libraries that I don't have installed. What kind of libraries can they be?

Comment: Here is the code that I'm running based on what you shared, see if any of the inputs   differ - http://tpcg.io/_BAV1LQ . The scipy in this environment is `1.10.1` but still the resulting angles are within bounds.

I also tried it locally on a fresh conda environment only with `scipy==1.14.1` installed, so I don't think there are any special libraries.

Comment: Your variant is work right in tutorialspoint.com. But it work not right in pycharm community. I have main code. It uses the ROOT library, which is not available on the site.

Comment: I noticed that pycharm shows scipy version 1.2.3. Now I'm trying to update this. I'm sorry for the last comments.